# python3-catkin-pkg-modules dependency apparently not available for Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy when building ROS2 from source

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, dependencies, build-from-source

I have been following the guides at [Using ros1_bridge with upstream ROS on Ubuntu 22.04](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Using-ros1_bridge-Jammy-upstream.html) and [Ubuntu (source)](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html) to build ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy. I've tried this for Iron and Humble.

When I try for example:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y --skip-keys "fastcdr rti-connext-dds-6.0.1 urdfdom_headers" --os=ubuntu:jammy --rosdistro humble
```

it fails with:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3-catkin-pkg-modules
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python3-catkin-pkg-modules] failed
```

I've looked on https://index.ros.org/d/python3-catkin-pkg-modules/ and there is nothing there for Jammy.

UPDATE:

I might be jumping the gun but rosdep install now fails for a different reason:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed
  python3-catkin-pkg-modules
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 8 not to upgrade.
Need to get 43.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 258 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 python3-catkin-pkg-modules all 1.0.0-1 [43.2 kB]
Fetched 43.2 kB in 0s (87.3 kB/s)               
Selecting previously unselected package python3-catkin-pkg-modules.
(Reading database ... 227933 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-catkin-pkg-modules_1.0.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-catkin-pkg-modules (1.0.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_1.0.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/__init__.py', which is also in package python3-catkin-pkg 0.4.24-2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_1.0.0-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python3-catkin-pkg-modules] failed
```

Comment: Are you using the ros apt repositories- does `grep packages.ros /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` show anything?

Comment: ```grep packages.ros /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*``` gives ```deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy main``` @LucasWalter

Comment: You'll need to disable those, add a `#` to the start of the deb lines referencing packages.ros.org or delete /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list or similar entirely and run `sudo apt update` after.  Then follow the https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Using-ros1_bridge-Jammy-upstream.html#install-development-tools-and-ros-tools instructions (don't follow the 'Installing ROS 2 from Source' link above that section)

Comment: You do need to follow the vcs import steps from https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#get-ros-2-code and colcon build it (but don't do the rosdep steps)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem here, following the same instructions. Solution was to `pip` install the packages that failed to install via `apt` (e.g. `pip install -U catkin-pkg-modules`).Next, added the failing apt install to `--skip-keys`. So, my working `rosdep` command eventually looked like this:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y --skip-keys "fastcdr rti-connext-dds-6.0.1 urdfdom_headers ignition-cmake2 ignition-math6 python3-catkin-pkg-modules python3-rosdistro-modules python3-vcstool" --rosdistro humble
```

Still working on getting ROS2 built, but this got me a step further.